# Cannot seem to vertically space items with flexbox. Flex: column and space-around doesn't seem to work

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I looked this problem up and found nothing that work. Making the parent flex and then the child `flex-direction: column` w/ space-between/space-evenly doesn't seem to work.

I've recreated everything in this codepen, but I really have no idea how I can make the page look like this in regards to space...

What am I missing?

Cheers!

codepen:
https://codepen.io/LovelyAndy/pen/LYbqzwG

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="welcome-page-container">
    <div class="all-els">
      <div class="text">
        <div class="t-h1">My Dad's Shit</div>
        <div class="t-h2">All this shit ain't gunna sort itself!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="btns">
        <button class="t-nav-switch">Sign In</button>
        <button class="t-nav-switch">Register</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Sass

```
.welcome-page-container
  width: 375px
  height: 812px
  border: 3px solid red
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  text-align: center
  padding-top: 3rem
  padding-left: 3rem
  padding-right: 3rem
.all-els
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: center
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating welcome `welcome-page-container`
as it didnt have any children...

Flex works in respect of their children

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="welcome-page-container">
<div class="all-els">
  <div class="text">
    <div class="t-h1">My Dad's Shit</div>
    <div class="t-h2">All this shit ain't gunna sort itself!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btns">
    <button class="t-nav-switch">Sign In</button>
    <button class="t-nav-switch">Register</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
  .welcome-page-container
  width: 375px
  height: 812px
  border: 3px solid red
  align-items: center
  text-align: center
  padding-top: 3rem
  padding-left: 3rem
  padding-right: 3rem
.all-els
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: center
  .text
    border: 5px solid cyan
    height: 150px
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: space-evenly
  
div
  border: 2px solid lime
  
.all-els
  border: 2px solid goldenrod
  height: 100%
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: space-evenly
```

---

## To be more precise

here is what you want with minor changes to the code.
The only changes I made were removing some divs
and adding `justify-content: space-evenly` and `flex-direction: column`

HTML

```
<div class="welcome-page-container">
    <div class="t-h1">My Dad's Shit</div>
    <div class="t-h2">All this shit ain't gunna sort itself!</div>
  <div>
    <button class="t-nav-switch">Sign In</button>
    <button class="t-nav-switch">Register</button>
  </div>
```

sass

```
.welcome-page-container
  width: 375px
  height: 812px
  border: 3px solid red
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: space-evenly
  align-items: center
  text-align: center
  padding-top: 3rem
  padding-left: 3rem
  padding-right: 3rem
.all-els
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: center
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `.all-els` does not have a `height`, so it has no place to put `space-beetwen`

you can try

```
.all-els
  height: 60% // added
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: center
```

[image: resukt]

Comment: Makes sense! Cheers!

Comment: @LovelyAndy no worries, glad i could help! Thank you for formulating your question in a way making it easy to understand